# A run-time error 438 when defining conditional formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to write an Excel macro to set up a conditional formatting for a sheet in my workbook called "Results" . Essentially, the desired outcome is to highlight all cells that begin with an exclamation mark ("!"). I know that the solution must be simple yet I keep getting the following error: 'Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method  ' and I just can't figure out how to make it work.

Debugger shows that the error occurs on the 5th line i.e.  .Interior.Color ....

```
Sub ResultsFormating()

Sheets("Results").Select
With Cells.FormatConditions
  .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=left(A1,1) = ""!"" "
  .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With

End Sub
```

a little help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.Interior` is a member of the newly added `FormatCondition` object, not the `FormatConditions` collection. Also it is good practice to `.Delete` the old format conditions (if any) before setting a new one, unless the purpose is to really create many for the same range.

Try this:

```
Sub ResultsFormating()
  With Sheets("Results").Cells.FormatConditions
    .Delete  
    With .Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=left(A1,1) = ""!"" ")
      .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Figuring this out would probably take me at least another couple of hours filled with frustration. Thank you!

Comment: @JaromirSida use the `Worksheets` collection instead of `Sheets` if you're looking for a `Worksheet` object, and extract that object reference into its own `Worksheet` local variable; that way you will get IntelliSense with early-bound member calls, instead of working blindly off an `Object` returned by the `Sheets` (or `Worksheets`) collection.

Comment: @Mat'sMug That's a cute advice. Could use the sheet's codename also. Unfortunately neither `with sheets(..)` nor `with worksheets(...)` activates intellisense.. :(

Comment: Correct. Hence extracting the result into a local variable. `Dim sheet As Worksheet`, `Set sheet = Worksheets("Results")`, `With sheet` - the `With` block will then be working off the `Worksheet` interface instead of `Object`.

Comment: While I understand it for `Sheets(...)`, Beats me why `Worksheets(...)` does not return the worksheet interface. But anyway, your advice is sound and helpful (though should lead to less questions on SO :P )